Add a 1-column table in a 2-column format document class without white spaces
How to add a 1-column table in a 2-column format document class?
Way 1:
\onecolumn
my longtable
\twocolumn

Above creates white spaces:

on the page that is before the table (has 5 lines in 1 column, the rest is blank)

my table is on a new page, but 50% of the page below is blank.

the following page has my remaining text in 2 columns.


Way 2:
There is an alternate way here How to use just one column page in documents?
They suggest using multicol. However, since I am in documentclass, I can't use multicol right after begin{document} as it splits my document into 4 columns.
I instead tried using it around my table.
\begin{multicol}{1}
my longtable
\end{multicol}

This is overwriting my table text over 2 columns.

\onecolumn forces a new page but does not usually force a blank page, if you are getting a blank page that is due to code not shown, make a small complete document that shows the problem then someone could help

Thank you, I have edited my question. I was referring to white spaces, not entirely blank pages. Sorry for not making it clear in the question.

Welcome tex.SE @Tarzan As wrote David, you need to "show" your real issue with a MWE so you can have helpful answers. For example, I do understand your "white spaces" as "page break" too, what happens with standard \onecolumn and \twocolumn anyway. You may also investigate use of tabular* environment...

there is still no information in your question that allows anyone to answer. does your table need to be longtable (i.e. does it span more than one page)? if not, the you can use \begin{table*} to make a table that spans across both columns. Otherwise use \onecolumn but place that in the source at a suitable plave to make a good page break.  You are specifying where the page break should happen, so if you get a bad page break with unwanted space you need to change your code (that you have not shown) it is impossible to help if you do not show the problem.

that is use method one but fix "on the page that is before the table (has 5 lines in 1 column, the rest is blank)"  by moving those 5 lines after the table.

"my table is on a new page, but 50% of the page below is blank." if your table is only half a page long why are you using longtable which is for multi-page tables?

If you need to set your document in two column, then use the option twocolumn as class file option, e.g.,
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
...

Then, if you need to span either table or image into two column, then use the below option
\begin{figure*}
...
\end{figure*}

\begin{table*}
...
\end{table*}

As you didn't provide any details, I assumed that you are using the standard class article
